# how do i append a struct Person in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

I have a `struct Person`

```
struct Person {
    string name;
    int age;
    Person* next;
};
```

and i need to make a function that appends structs after each other like a linked list. I started off by creating a pointer head which is a nullpointer in the beginning.

```
using namespace std;
Person* head = nullptr;

void append(Person*& list, const string& name, int age) {
    auto p = new Person{name, age, nullptr}; // typ List_Node*
    if (list == nullptr) {
        list = p;
        return;
    }

    auto last = list;
    while (last != nullptr) {
        last = last->next;
    }
    last = p;
}

int main() {
    append(head, "First_Person", 21);
    append(head, "Second_Person", 22);
    // testing the result
    head = head->next;
    cout << "head->name outside: " << head->name << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Now the problem i have now is that after the first append the `append()` function doesn't seem to link the first person to the second person because the program crashes

```
head = head->next;
```

Question is: how do i get `append()` to append more than 1 Person to this linked list?

Comment: Use `std::vector` or `std::list` to hold your `Person` items, then you can simply `push_back()` a new `Person` when needed.

Comment: If you got rid of the `next` member, `std::forward_list<Person>` would be identical to what you have, but better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    auto last = list;
    while (last != nullptr){
        last = last->next;
    }
    last = p;
```

When you get out of this loop, `last` is pointing at `nullptr` again instead of the last element of the list.  You need to check `last->next != nullptr` instead.

Also, `last = p` does not do anything useful; it should be `last->next = p` in order to actually append `p` to the list.

Comment: Hope you don't mind the edit, feel free to roll back if you disagree.

Answer (score 0):

Your `append()` is not managing the pointers correctly.  Try this instead:

```
void append(Person*& list, const string& name, int age)
{
    auto p = new Person{name, age, nullptr}; // typ List_Node*

    if (list == nullptr)
    {
        list = p;
        return;
    }

    auto last = list;
    while (last->next != nullptr)
        last = last->next;

    last->next = p;
}
```

If you get rid of the `list` parameter, you can avoid having to iterate through the *entire list* on every append:

```
Person* head = nullptr;
Person* last = nullptr;

void append(const string& name, int age)
{
    auto p = new Person{name, age, nullptr};

    if (head == nullptr)
        head = p;

    if (last != nullptr)
        last->next = p;

    last = p;
}

int main()
{
    append("First_Person", 21);
    append("Second_Person", 22);

    //testing the result
    for(Person *p = head; p != nullptr; p = p->next)
        std::cout << "name: " << p->name << std::endl;

    // free the list
    Person *p = head;
    while (p != nullptr)
    {
        Person *next = p->next;
        delete p;
        p = next;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

That being said, you should use `std::list` or `std::forward_list` to hold your `Person` items and let it handle all of these details for you, eg:

```
#include <list> // or: #include <forward_list>

struct Person
{
    string name;
    int age;
};

std::list<Person> mylist; // or: std::forward_list<Person> mylist;

void append(const string& name, int age)
{
    mylist.push_back(Person{name, age});
}

int main()
{
    append("First_Person", 21);
    append("Second_Person", 22);

    //testing the result
    for (auto &person: mylist)
        std::cout << "name: " << person.name << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::list<Person> list;` : the name might be ambiguous within `append`, I would have chosen another one : ) (see [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f6d1171c4ad109ec) )

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing this in a non-academic context, then don't reinvent the wheel, and use a standard container like vector or list.

However, assuming the point of the exercise is to learn data structures, then using a builtin container doesn't teach you much.

The problem I see is you are doing nothing but changing the "last" pointer, which doesn't actually *append* anything to the list. You need to first find the last node (by using the 'last' pointer to move to each node->next until you reach a node which has a null ->next pointer. Then assign that node's ->next to your new node.

Your existing code...

```
// Already handled empty list case before we get here...

auto last = list;  // last pointer set to address list (head)
while (last != nullptr){    // while not at end of list, last points to next node
    last = last->next;
}
                   // after loop, last will always be null, not very useful
last = p;          // last points to p (the new node) which doesn't _do_ anything
```

Consider doing something like:

```
// Already handled empty list case before we get here...

auto last = list;  // last pointer set to address list (head)
while (last && last->next != nullptr){    // while node->next not null, move to next node
    last = last->next;
}
                   // at end of list, last will always point to last node
last->next = p;    // link last->next to the new 'p' Person
```

Keep in mind if you do a lot of list append operations, it is cheaper for your list data structure to keep a head and a tail pointer, and append simply becomes

```
if(tail)
    tail->next = p;
tail = p;
```

Besides that, it is cheaper to insert items at the head of a list.

```
p->next = head;
head = p;
```